# Sum of all residues of $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ be two polynomials such that $deg(Q) ≥ 2 + deg(P)$. Suppose {$z_{1}, . . . , z_{n}$} is the set of all distinct poles of $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$. Show that $\sum{Res(\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}; z_{j})} = 0$.

I know we can take a contour that contains all the poles and use $Res(\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)},\infty)=0$ to show the sum of Res above is zero. I just wonder if there is another to prove it?

Comment: Maybe using [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)... but I envision complex stuff depending on pole orders.